# JAAS authentication in JMS using WildFly : javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly, jaas, hornetq

Using WildFly 9.0.2 final, the `<hornetq-server>` section is defined in `standalone-full.xml` as follows.

<sub>Sections like `<address-settings>`, `<acceptors>` and `<connectors>` are completely omitted as I did not change anything in them.</sub>

```xml
<hornetq-server>
    <security-domain>ProjectRealm</security-domain>
    <security-enabled>true</security-enabled>
    <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>

    <security-settings>
        <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="send" roles="ROLE_USER ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="ROLE_USER ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="ROLE_USER ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="ROLE_USER ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="ROLE_USER ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="ROLE_USER ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </security-setting>
    </security-settings>    

    <jms-connection-factories>        
        <connection-factory name="destinationFactory">
            <connectors>
                <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
            </connectors>
            <entries>
                <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/destinationFactory"/>
            </entries>
        </connection-factory>        
    </jms-connection-factories>

    <jms-destinations>        
        <jms-queue name="userStatusQueue">
            <entry name="jms/destination"/>
            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/destination"/>
        </jms-queue>
    </jms-destinations>
</hornetq-server>
```

It defines a connection factory named `destinationFactory` which uses `http-connector` and a queue named `userStatusQueue` which are bound to a JNDI name as listed in the nested `<entry>` element.

It also defines a security domain.

```xml
<security-domain>ProjectRealm</security-domain>
```

Security is enabled (default) using,

```xml
<security-enabled>true</security-enabled>
```

In which case, it causes the following exception to be thrown.

```
15:49:28,093 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-2) java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.jms.JMSSecurityRuntimeException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.jms.JMSSecurityRuntimeException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:296)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:128)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:89)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at filter.LoginNocacheFilter.doFilter(LoginNocacheFilter.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:122)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.jms.JMSSecurityRuntimeException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:219)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:643)
    at admin.bean.SignInCheck.signIn(SignInCheck.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityRuntimeException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.JmsExceptionUtils.convertToRuntimeException(JmsExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSProducer.send(HornetQJMSProducer.java:112)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSProducer.send(HornetQJMSProducer.java:135)
    at filter.SecurityCheck.sendMessageToDestination(SecurityCheck.java:54)
    at filter.SecurityCheck.doAfterProcessing(SecurityCheck.java:107)
    at filter.SecurityCheck.doFilter(SecurityCheck.java:161)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:198)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:195)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}
    at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:399)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:334)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:304)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:135)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.doSendx(HornetQMessageProducer.java:524)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.send(HornetQMessageProducer.java:210)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.send(HornetQMessageProducer.java:200)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSProducer.send(HornetQJMSProducer.java:107)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: HornetQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}]
    ... 95 more
```

Message is sent through the defined queue (which is received by a Message Driven Bean (MDB)), when `<security-enabled>` is given a `false` value. I however need only the users who have a predefined authority/role (`ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_USER`) to create the queue and send messages across.

The approach using `<security-domain>` as shown above fails with the above exception.

I tried adding roles in `/standalone/configuration/application-roles.properties` exactly as defined in the `ProjectRealm.properties` file used in

```xml
<module-option name="rolesProperties"
               value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/ProjectRealm.properties"/>
```

inside `<login-module>` but it did not help either.

```
admins=ROLE_ADMIN
users=ROLE_USER
```

What more needs to be done to authenticate users before sending messages across the queue?

---

**Additional :**

The JAAS security manager uses the following domain to authenticate and authorize users using a JDBC realm (XA datasource). This already works fine.

```xml
<security-domain name="ProjectRealm" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/projectXADatasource"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM user_table WHERE email_id=?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT user_role, 'Roles' FROM user_roles ur INNER JOIN user_table ut ON ur.user_id=ut.user_id WHERE ut.email_id=?"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
            <module-option name="hashCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
            <module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="false"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>

        <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="required">
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/ProjectRealm.properties"/>
            <module-option name="replaceRole" value="false"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

The queue is injected in an authentication Servlet filter which is used by `JMSContext` to send a message across the queue after a user is successfully authenticated and authorize.

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityCheck", urlPatterns = {"/WEB-INF/jaas/*"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD})
public final class SecurityCheck implements Filter {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/destination")
    private Queue queue;

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:jboss/exported/jms/destinationFactory")
    private JMSContext context;
    // jms/destinationFactory is expected to work here but it only works using the fully qualified namespace as above.

    public SecurityCheck() {}

    private void sendMessageToDestination(String message) throws JMSException {
        context.createProducer().send(queue, message);
    }

    private void doBeforeProcessing(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        request.login(userName.trim(), request.getParameter("password"));
    }

    private void doAfterProcessing(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException, JMSException {

        if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            sendMessageToDestination("Message");
            // Redirect to a secure area.
        } else if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_USER")) {
            sendMessageToDestination("Message");
            // Redirect to a secure area.
        }

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

I am using a self-signed SSL certificate for a pure testing purpose. Thus, it uses `https://localhost:8443/ContextPath` for accessing secured web resources

`<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` in `web.xml`.

---

**Update :**

The Message Driven Bean consuming messages :

```
@JMSDestinationDefinition(name = "destination", interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue", resourceAdapter = "jmsra", destinationName = "destination")
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/destination"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/destinationFactory"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messagingType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.MessageListener"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/destination"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true")
})
public class UserStatusMessageBean implements MessageListener {

    public UserStatusMessageBean() {}

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext messageDrivenContext;
    @EJB
    private UserStatusService userStatusService;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                String text = textMessage.getText();

                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(text)) {
                    userStatusService.addHost(text);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No message found.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Message is of wrong type : " + message.getClass().getName());
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            messageDrivenContext.setRollbackOnly();
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a remote EJB being injected into the above MDB which requires defined authorities.

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"})
@RolesAllowed(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"})
public class UserStatusBean implements UserStatusService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void addHost(String hostName) {
        // Insert or update via JPA.
    }
}
```

When the application is deployed, the server keeps on throwing following exception recursively unless a `false` value is given in,

```xml
<security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
```

```
20:21:55,343 ERROR [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 3) HQ154003: Unable to reconnect org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@dc9e56 destination=java:/jms/destination destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15): HornetQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=CONSUME on address {2}]
    at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:399)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.internalCreateConsumer(ClientSessionImpl.java:2064)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.createConsumer(ClientSessionImpl.java:527)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionImpl.createConsumer(ClientSessionImpl.java:474)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.DelegatingSession.createConsumer(DelegatingSession.java:206)
    at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.setup(HornetQMessageHandler.java:184)
    at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation.setup(HornetQActivation.java:340)
    at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation.handleFailure(HornetQActivation.java:768)
    at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation$SetupActivation.run(HornetQActivation.java:823)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.run(WorkWrapper.java:226)
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:828)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced the same issue on WildFly 9.0.2, (using a REST EJB resource instead of your Servlet)

```
23:31:22,138 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-7) UT005023: Exception handling request to /jeeshop-admin/rs/users/administrators: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
```

To fix it I did the following:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/exported/jms/destinationFactory")
ConnectionFactory factory;

private void sendMessageToDestination(String message, String user) throws JMSException {
    try (Connection connection = factory.createConnection(user,"hardcodedPassword");
         Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue)) {

        TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);

        producer.send(textMessage);
    }
}
```

So as you can see I'm providing a valid user name and password, during connection creation. This user has the same role as the one configured in hornetq-server security settings.

I did not use exactly the same security domain as you then (I used my own code to reproduce your issue). 
In case yours does not work well, here it is:

```xml
<security-domain name="jeeshop" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/JeeshopDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from User where login = ? and (disabled is null or disabled = 0) and activated = 1"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select name,'Roles' from Role r, User_Role ur, User u where u.login=? and u.id = ur.userId and r.id = ur.roleId"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

My datasource:

```xml
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/JeeshopDS" pool-name="JeeshopDS" enabled="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
        localhost
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
        jeeshop
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>jeeshop</user-name>
        <password>test</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

Extract of my DDL for Roles storage:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Role (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY UK_Role_name (name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User_Role (
  userId bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  roleId bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userId,roleId)
);
```

**EDIT**

The following MDB allows to read the destination where `sendMessageToDestination()` produces messages:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/destination"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
public class TestMDB implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    @PermitAll
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                // propagate for transaction rollback
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You could eventually change Principal used by MDB. See these links:

- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/jboss-ejb3.xml+Reference
- https://developer.jboss.org/message/836356

Comment: These changes have been made. This exception occurs at **deployment time** : `17:17:31,687 ERROR [org.hornetq.ra] (default-threads - 1) HQ154003: Unable to reconnect org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@a0f08f destination=jms/destination destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15): HornetQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=HQ119032: User: null doesn't have permission=CONSUME on address {2}]`...

Comment: ... before the queue gets a chance to send a message at **run-time** unless a `false` value is given in `<security-enabled>true</security-enabled>` and all `roles` attributes in `<permission>` are reset to `guest`.

Comment: The target Message Driven Bean (MDB) injecting an EJB with authorities : `@RolesAllowed(value = {"ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"})` causes the `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException` to be thrown.

Comment: For you information, when I met the same exception as yours "User: null doesn't have permission", it was during execution of the sendMessageToDestination method, before I added any user and password information while creating the connexion, which fixed the issue. Deployment works fine for me, but I don't have any MDB as I wanted to reproduce your message sending error. What did you change exactly, since you have another exception during MDB startup now (CONSUME) ? It would help if you could share your project sources to github or other platform.

Comment: I have updated the question. In addition to the update, changes to the `sendMessageToDestination()` method have been made.

Comment: I've added the MDB I used to read messages to destination used by sendMessageToDestination. Messages are read successfully by MDB thanks to @PermitAll. I've simplified Activation Spec properties compared to your version

Comment: The GlassFish Server does not require `@PermitAll` on the `onMessage()` method. Only annotating the MDB with `@RunAs("ROLE_ADMIN")` is sufficient there in GlassFish. It was the major confusion. (FYI : I will explicitly complete the bounty during its grace period. Thanks).

Comment: Do you know why queues and connection factories require a fully qualified namespace starting with `java:jboss/exported` for a JNDI lookup? It should not be required as [documented](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Messaging+configuration#Messagingconfiguration-JMSQueuesandTopics).

Comment: "*As with connection factories, if a jms-queue or jms-topic has an entry bound in the `java:jboss/exported` namespace a remote client would look it up using the text after `java:jboss/exported`.  For example, the following jms-queue `testQueue` is bound to `java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test` which means a remote client would look-up this jms-queue using `jms/queue/test`.  A local client could look it up using `java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test`, `java:jms/queue/test`, or more simply `jms/queue/test`.*"

Comment: Don't think you need that actually. In [this article](https://gist.github.com/remibantos/33c366803f189db9b225) I'd just configured a destination with jndi-name attribute set to "java:/jboss/test" and referenced it in MDB with propertyValue = "jndi-name="java:/jboss/test"